# ActivityNotFoundException while using ZXing

Tags: android, zxing

Android 2.3.3

As with most of the people using `ZXing` (new to using `ZXing`), I am getting the `ActivityNotFoundException` (I guess there is no need to paste my logcat as it's the same with all other people).

I have seen few questions related to `ActivityNotFoundException` with `ZXing`. Here is what I have understood so far. Please correct me if I am wrong..

If I have to use `ZXing` in my app, there are two options :

1. I can use the `Intent` and `startActivityForResult()`, if the user already has the `ZXing` application installed, and if doesn't, I can redirect him to the playstore to install it first and then use my application.
2. For my application to work, even if the `ZXing` application is not installed, I can add `ZXing` library to my project as a library, copy the code of `IntentIntegrator` class(from [here](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java)) into a seperate class in my application and use `IntentIntegrator`. Is this the intended purpose of `IntentIntegrator`? or Am I getting it completely wrong?

Can someone help me with my doubts?

EDIT::: Seems like the second approach also needs to have the `ZXing` application installed on the device. Is there a way, that my application can work, without the need of `ZXing` app installation?

Comment: Have you included activities in manifest

Comment: I should probably be including the activities in manifest, If I want to copy the files into my project. But, that's not what I want.

Comment: You must have to include com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity activity in manifest. Please check.

Comment: So, I have to include all the activities in my manifest, that I want to use? Let's say I want to use a class from com.google.zxing.client.android.share, do I have to include that as well in my manifest?

Comment: IntentIntegrator is for when you integrate with the Barcode Scanner app externally, only. Please don't copy our app into yours.

Comment: yes, you must have to include all of them.

Comment: @SeanOwen, Yeah, I only want to use them and not copy your code.

Comment: @Amit, Ok, I will give it a try

Comment: Include only activities want to use not all classes.

Comment: Check the link may help you http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't installed Barcode Scanner. Please use the `IntentIntegrator` as directed already in the documentation: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

It will handle installation for you.